# Ada - Function within a package. Error says the package should end where the function ends

Tags: function, oop, package, ada

When I try to run the program I'm getting an error stating "end Animals;" is expected where I end the function 'Init'. I'm quite new to programming and I just can't figure out what the problem is. It's trying to get me to change it to 'end Animals;' but then that will end the package there and not run the rest of it.

```
package body Animals is

   function Init(
                 Name : in String;
                 Legs : in Natural;
                 WeightInGrams : in Positive;
                 HeightInCm : in Positive)
                 return Creature;
   TempCreature : Creature;
begin
   TempCreature.Name := To_Unbounded_String(Name);
   TempCreature.Legs := Legs;
   TempCreature.WeightInGrams := WeightInGrams;
   TempCreature.HeightInCm := HeightInCm;
   return TempCreature;
end Init;                                                ***--"end Animals;" expected***

function Init return Creature is
   TempCreature : Creature;
begin
   TempCreature.Name := To_Unbounded_String("Dog");
   TempCreature.Legs := 4;
   TempCreature.WeightInGrams := 3000;
   TempCreature.HeightInCm := 40;
   return TempCreature;
end Init;

procedure Set_Legs(
                   Creat : in out Creature;
                   Legs : in Natural) is
begin
   Creat.Legs := Legs;
end Set_Legs;

procedure Set_Weight(
                     Creat : in out Creature;
                     WeightInGrams : in Positive) is
begin
   Creat.WeightInGrams := WeightInGrams;
end Set_Weight;

procedure Set_Height(
                     Creat : in out Creature;
                     HeightInCm : in Positive) is
begin
   Creat.HeightInCm := HeightInCm;
end Set_Height;

function Get_Legs(
                  Creat : in out Creature)
                  return Natural is
begin
   return Creat.Legs;
end Get_Legs;

function Get_Weight(
                    Creat : in out Creature)
                    return Positive is
begin
   return Creat.WeightInGrams;
end Get_Weight;

function Get_Height(
                    Creat : in out Creature)
                    return Positive is
begin
   return Creat.HeightInCm;
end Get_Height;

overriding procedure Finalize(
                              Creat : in out Creature) is
begin
   Put_Line("Resetting values of Creat to defaults.");
   Creat.Name := Null_Unbounded_String;
   Creat.Legs := 0;
   Creat.WeightInGrams := 1;
   Creat.HeightIncm := 1;
end Finalize;

procedure Print_Record(Creat : in out Creature) is
begin
   Private_Print_Record(Creat);
end Print_Record;

procedure Private_Print_Record(Creat : in out Creature) is
begin
   Put_Line("The animal: ");
   Put_Line("The name: " & To_String(Creat.Name));
   Put_Line("Number of legs: " & Natural'Image(Creat'Legs));
   Put_Line("Weight in grams: " & Positive'Image(Creat.WeightInGrams));
   Put_Line("Height in cm: " & Positive'image(Creat.HeightInCm));
end Private_Print_Record;
end Animals;
```

Comment: DeeDee already answered, but here's a tip for the future: If you look at the indentation, it's clear that something is not quite right.. So your IDE gave you a clue in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you made typo at the end of the function declaration.

```
 function Init(
                 Name : in String;
                 Legs : in Natural;
                 WeightInGrams : in Positive;
                 HeightInCm : in Positive)
                 return Creature;            --  remove ";" add "is"
   TempCreature : Creature;
begin
   -- ...
end Init;
```

should be

```
function Init
   (Name          : in String;
    Legs          : in Natural;
    WeightInGrams : in Positive;
    HeightInCm    : in Positive) return Creature
is
   TempCreature : Creature;
begin
   -- ...
end Init;
```